# How to display graph with defined color when data is not available in Victory Pie?

Tags: javascript, victory-charts

Right now when I set the y's value 0 then the graph will not be visible but here I want to display the circle or victory pie gray in color when y's all values are 0. 
Is there any path in victory Pie to display the graph with the gray color when data is not available?

```
<VictoryPie
 colorScale={["tomato", "orange", "gold"]}
   data={[
    { x: "Cats", y: 35 },
    { x: "Dogs", y: 40 },
    { x: "Birds", y: 55 }
  ]}
/>
```

Right now graph looks like this when data is available
[image]

The expected output of a graph should be like below when data is not available or y's values are 0.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This following code is not focusing on syntax errors or any other thing. This example just focusing on the logic of how we can display a graph when graph data is not available.

```
 const graph_data = data || your_y_value_present
        ? [
            { x: "Cats", y: 35 },
            { x: "Dogs", y: 40 },
            { x: "Birds", y: 55 }
        ]
        : [{ y: 1 }];

 const color_scale = data || your_y_value_present
        ? ["tomato", "orange", "gold"]
        : ["grey"];

<VictoryPie
   colorScale={color_scale }
   data={graph_data }
/>
```